# Copy data from pointers into a void * buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, void-pointers

**tldr:** My Goal is to copy all the data where pointers are refering to, to a void buffer.

So I have multiple pointer with different types, which are pointing to their data

```
const unsigned char * pData8u1 = pContainer1->GetData();
const float * pData32f1 = pContainer2->GetData();
...
const unsigned long long * pData64uN = pContainerN->GetData();
```

I store the pointers in a void vector and their dataSize in a size_t vector, so I can iterate through all pointers

```
std::vector<const void *> vecData;
std::vector<const size_t> vecDataSizes;
```

My Goal is to copy all the data where the pointers are refering to, to a void buffer

```
void * destinationBuffer // should contain all data
```

This buffer has a size. I assume:

```
inputDataSize = std::accumulate(vecDataSizes.begin(), vecDataSizes.end(), 0); 
if(inputDataSize == destinationBufferSize && inputDataSize != 0) // condition
{
  // do copy
}
```

How do I copy the data referenced by the pointers to this buffer? I am a bit lost. I tried different ideas (memcpy, copy, ...) but could not realize them.
An easy solution would be great, an efficient solution would be a bonus :)

Comment: How did your attempts fail?

Comment: `void * destinationBuffer ` is not a buffer. Its just a pointer (that can point to some buffer)

Comment: Either memcpy or copy would work. Can you show your attempts? It's so much easier to understand and fix the problem when you can see the failed attempts.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand WHY you want to do that.

But you can simply use `std::copy` in a loop. Or `memcpy`. Or tons of other possibilities. Of course you can only copy trivial data. But that is  independent of this question and generally applicable for copying data at a certain memory address.

Here is one example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    // Some different Data types
    std::vector <unsigned char> uc{ 0,1,2,3,4 };
    std::vector <short> ss{ 5,6,7 };
    std::vector <unsigned int> ui{ 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    std::vector <long> sl{ 16,17 };
    std::vector <unsigned long long> ull{ 18,19,20,21,22,23 };

    // pointers to these data types
    std::vector<void*> vptr {
        uc.data(),
        ss.data(),
        ui.data(),
        sl.data(),
        ull.data() 
    };

    // Sizes of the above types
    std::vector<size_t> csize {
        uc.size() * sizeof(decltype(uc)::value_type),
        ss.size() * sizeof(decltype(ss)::value_type),
        ui.size() * sizeof(decltype(ui)::value_type),
        sl.size() * sizeof(decltype(sl)::value_type),
        ull.size() * sizeof(decltype(ull)::value_type)
    };

    // Calculate overall size in bytes
    size_t overallSize = std::accumulate(csize.begin(), csize.end(), 0);

    // Get destination memory
    std::byte* destinationBuffer = new std::byte[overallSize];
    // Some intermediate pointer
    std::byte* destinationAdress = destinationBuffer;

    // Copy
    for (size_t i{}; i < vptr.size(); ++i) {
        destinationAdress = std::copy((std::byte*)vptr[i], (std::byte*)vptr[i] + csize[i], destinationAdress);
    }

    // Debug output
    for (size_t i{}; i < overallSize; ++i)
        std::cout << ((int)destinationBuffer[i]) << ' ';

    // Release memory
    delete[]destinationBuffer;
}
```

---

And if your containers have a common interface to get its data and its size, then you can write a variadic function which takes any number of containers and copies the data.

A `std::vector` is for example such a container. It has a `data()` and a `size()` function.

An example solution with some variadic template function and fold expressions would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...Args>
std::pair<void*, size_t> copyData(const std::vector<Args>& ...args) {

    size_t overallSize = (0 + ... + (args.size() * sizeof(std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(args)>::value_type)));
    std::byte* destination = new std::byte[overallSize];

    std::byte* destinationAddress = destination;

    ((destinationAddress = std::copy((std::byte*)args.data(), (std::byte*)args.data() + (args.size() * sizeof(std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(args)>::value_type)), 
        destinationAddress)), ...);

    return { destination, overallSize };
}

int main() {
    // Some demo data with different data types
    std::vector <unsigned char> uc{ 0,1,2,3,4 };
    std::vector <short> ss{ 5,6,7 };
    std::vector <unsigned int> ui{ 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    std::vector <long> sl{ 16,17 };
    std::vector <unsigned long long> ull{ 18,19,20,21,22,23 };

    // Call function with any number of arguments
    const auto& [pointer, size] = copyData(uc, ss, ui, sl, ull);

    // Some debug output
    for (size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << ((int)((std::byte*)(pointer))[i]) << ' ';

    delete[] pointer;
}
```

---

And going one step ahead. If we just assume containers having certain properties, like `::value`, a `data()` and a `size()` function, then we can even be more generic.

In the below example I hand in `std::vector`s and `std::array`s

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...Args>
std::pair<void*, size_t> copyData(Args...args) {
    static_assert((std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(args.data())>> && ...),"Not trivially copyable");

    size_t overallSize = (0 + ... + (args.size() * sizeof(std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(args)>::value_type)));
    std::byte* destination = new std::byte[overallSize];

    std::byte* destinationAddress = destination;

    ((destinationAddress = std::copy((std::byte*)args.data(), (std::byte*)args.data() + (args.size() * sizeof(std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(args)>::value_type)),
        destinationAddress)), ...);

    return { destination, overallSize };
}

int main() {
    // Some demo data with different data types
    std::vector <unsigned char> uc{ 0,1,2,3,4 };
    std::array <short, 3> ss{ 5,6,7 };
    std::vector <unsigned int> ui{ 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    std::array <long, 2> sl{ 16,17 };
    std::vector <unsigned long long> ull{ 18,19,20,21,22,23 };

    // Call function with any number of arguments
    const auto& [pointer, size] = copyData(uc, ss, ui, sl, ull);

    // Some debug output
    for (size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << ((int)((std::byte*)(pointer))[i]) << ' ';

    delete[] pointer;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion, use the return value of `std::copy` to update the pointer into the output buffer instead of manually advancing it. The algorithm gives you the next destination address for free. That saves a little calculation and simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: This will fail when the objects aren't trivially copyable. `memcpy()` will just do the wrong thing and `std::copy` will copy data on the heap according to the objects copy assignemnt to an uninitialized object (actually a non object as nothign lives there). Highly UB. I think you need to use `construct_at` with the copy constructor instead and C++20 to get out of UB land.